# throng giving log node/v12.6.0/bin/node: must be 0 or in range 1024 to 65535

Tags: node.js, port

When I use throng I got hungreds of logs `node/v12.6.0/bin/node:  must be 0 or in range 1024 to 65535.` before the processes start.

```js
const throng = require('throng');

throng({
workers: 3,
start: () => {
   console.log('test');
  },
});
```

Answer (score 0):

updating to node v14.18.2 with nvm fixed the issue. I had to completely remove v12.6.0 too.